# Proxying Backend Requests In NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I was trying to proxy requests to my backend. Going through docs, I found out that we can add a rewrite() function in config,

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: "",
  distDir: "build",
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["localhost"],
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: "/api/:path*",
          destination: "http://localhost:3001/todos/:path*",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

I tried this but it fails .It fires two request to API for one each, here the first request says 308 permanent redirect, and the second request says 404. And thats it, it does not requests the api.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3001/todos/:path*` your backend?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:3001/todos 
this is my api, running locally

Comment: have you already tried this wtihout `beforeFiles` ? i.e ```  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        destination: '/',
      },
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Yes I have used it without before files

Comment: Perhaps it would help for you to post the requesting code as well. For all we know, it could be saying `fetch('/apu/posts')` or something.